# Excel VBA rounding with doubles

Tags: excel, floating-point, double, rounding-error, vba

I am trying to do a very accurate calculation using doubles that relate to cells in my worksheet. As I test I wrote the following code:

```
Sub MacroTest()

Dim opt As Worksheet
Set opt = Sheets("Optimisation")

Dim test As Double

test = CDec(opt.Cells(2, 10))

End Sub
```

In the cell J2 is the decimal value -£3,298.8599993... however when debugging the code it is clear that the test double is only picking up -3298.86 as the value. I don't understand why this would be as I thought doubles were more accurate than this. Most of the posts I have read seem to think that using CDec should sort this problem out, however as shown this does not seem to work for me.

Note - The value in J2 has been calculated using a formula, not sure if this makes any difference. Any help is greatly appreciated - thanks.

Comment: Is the `Cell J2` formatted to show the number of digits you want after the point . ?

Comment: @ShaiRado Cell J2 is currently formatted to show 7 decimal places

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `opt.Cells(2, 10).Value2` in this case. [Range.Value2 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value2.aspx):

> The only difference between this property and the Value property is
>   that the Value2 property doesn’t use the Currency and Date data types.
>   You can return values formatted with these data types as
>   floating-point numbers by using the Double data type.

So the default `.Value` will return `Currency` if the cell is formatted as currency while `.Value2` will return a `Double` nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, but here is what is wrong with your code:

You are using a CDec-conversion formula on a double-datatype, and the result from this function is put into a double-datatype again.  So you do not gain anything here accuracy wise.

Are you sure you want to use the double-datatype, while you *could* use the decimal-datatype in VBA?

In my example, cell "A1" contains the decimal number 3298.859999.

```
Dim varDec As Variant
varDec = CDec(Range("A1").Value2)

Debug.Print "Value in A1 : " & Format(varDec, "0.0000000000000000000000")
```

Direct casting of a variable to the Decimal-datatype is not possible in VBA, but the Variant-datatype has the Decimal-datatype as a subtype.

To see this for yourself: look in the "Locals"-window in the VBE while debugging. It will show:

```
Expression : var
Value      : 3298.859999
Type       : Variant/Decimal
```

[Background article on Excel numeric precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel)